# pandas- selecting data from 2 different columns based on a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have 3 dataframes/series:

```
>>> max_q.head()
Out[16]: 
130    1.00
143    2.00
146    2.00
324   10.00
327    6.00
dtype: float64|

>>> min_q.head()
Out[17]: 
130   8.00
143   6.00
146   4.00
324   8.00
327   8.00
dtype: float64

>>> dirx.head()
Out[18]: 
    side
130    B
143    S
146    S
324    B
327    S
```

I want to create a new dataframe which equals max_q when dirx ='S' and min_q otherwise.

Is there a simple way to do this? the following have failed so far:

```
1.    np.where(dirx=='S', max_q, min_q)

2.    rp = pd.DataFrame(max_q, columns = ['id'])
      rp.loc[dirx=='B', 'id'] = min_q
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the indexes?

Comment: hi, yes that is preferable...i need to keep the order.

Comment: your code works here when adding `dirx['side'] = 'B'`. What happens if you do `max_q.index.duplicated()`?

Comment: What is wrong with your second method

Comment: @RafaelC >>> max_q.index.duplicated()
Out[79]: array([False, False, False, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)

Comment: do `any()` that..